# Phonegap + JQuery Mobile: Android crash when I click on a link

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've a problem with Phonegap + Android + JQuery Mobile.

Android close my application when I click on a link on the index.html but I don't know why...
the console of eclipse doesn't give me any error.

My Activity:

```
package it.test.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.phonegap.*;

public class testActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Example of a link in my index.html:

```
<a href="page_1.htm">Link</a>
```

I also created the same app for iPhone and iPad and all works right.

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: If you have the Android SDK installed, open up LogCat in Eclipse. That's where your error message will be shown.

Comment: Oh Thanks, The error is: 09-01 10:09:14.152: ERROR/ActivityManager(96): fail to set top app changed! But I found that removing JQuery Mobile, my app works... I think that there is a problem with the method of this framework that load pages with Ajax...

Comment: At the moment I be able to solve this problem adding rel="external" to any link but why this system used to load pages doesn't work on Android?

Comment: Not sure, it seems to work fine for me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After speding a lot of time looking for a solution i've found this bug of Android:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6593

In poor words Android doesn't like to get via ajax call an html or xml with this tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0;" />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="/pics/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

and generally all the "special tags" for mobile application.

Without this tags and the "rel" attributes on links all works like a charm.

ADB

Comment: Perfect, thanks!! 
Only one thing, I did some tests and with this tag works: 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0;" />